# glm.nb fails to converge when adding one zero

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I have a problem where `glm.nb` (R version 3.1.0, MASS version 7.3.33) converges on some data, but adding only one 0 it does not converge any more. This is the data

```
x <- c(3908,2729,10,803,1893,27,1312,1457,4534,3420,3,1608,903,1702,
       3041,1267,1381,3983,203,2202,1021,1550,1293,2572,1868,877,2317,
       2442, 1174,2450,1183,349)
```

`glm.nb(x~1)` converges fine, but when I run `glm.nb(c(x,0)~1)` it does not converge. `zeroinfl(c(x,0)~1, dist="negbin"`) converges estimating the zero probability at 0.029 (this is roughly `1/(length(x)+1)`). It seems that the problem is with `theta.ml`, which `glm.nb` uses. More precisely `theta.ml(c(x,0), 1681)` (1681 is the poisson estimate of `mu`) does not converge and this fails `glm.nb`.

To me adding one 0 seems like a benign thing to do (in this case), for such a dramatic change in behavior. My problem is bigger than the indication above, because I have many other pieces of data where `glm.nb/theta.ml` does not converge (most have more than one 0) and I am not sure what to do. I am trying to compare the negative binomial fit with its zero-inflated version (`zeroinf`) and am getting foiled because of this. Is the failure of `glm.nb` an indication that negative binomial is not appropriate? This might be the case for the examples with more 0's, but the above example with only one 0 is confusing me, because it makes me think that the problem is with the `theta.ml` code.

Any comments/suggestions? `theta.ml` seems to employ a simple iterative procedure and perhaps someone who understands it better can comment on its convergence properties.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical solvers are very difficult to visualize. The negative binomial GLM is an exact numerical solver for the somewhat complicated negative binomial likelihood. It is easier to visualize how the likelihood "appears" for regular plain vanilla GLMs like Poisson or quasipoisson models. It's quadratic. For NB likelihoods, any two different beta-coefficients for the "rate" parameter will lead to different optimal gamma "coefficients" for the shape parameter.

The estimation process, like mixed effects models, is done with expectation-maximization. What is the big implication for NB likelihoods? The existence and uniqueness of solutions to the likelihood is *not* guaranteed. The 0 that you are adding is so highly inconsistent with the likelihood for the existing data that the solutions are either on the boundary of the parameter space ($\pm \infty$) or there are multiple solutions. Adding one spurious 0 is far from benign. Even for "sane" estimation procedures, adding random values is never really benign, since if they are influence points, they will drastically influence results.

Adding a zero-inflated component to the likelihood simplifies things greatly... since the original NB likelihood *sans* 0 converged, you are making a heirarchical model that "explains" the 0 via another parameter. Effectively, you have removed the 0 observation from the NB model with that process.

Comment: Thanks, AdamO. This makes sense: I should be careful calling things benign. As far as the 0: the actual data (that came from an experiment) is with the 0 and glm.nb diverged. I just noticed that the removing it makes glm.nb converge and phrased my question as adding it..

Comment: In practical terms: what choice do I have? I wanted to compare the NB fit  with the ZINB fit. Is it safe for me to say that because of the zero, the data is not NB distributed? I was hoping to get a more quantitative answer, but perhaps failure to converge is the best I can get. Its just that divergence seems to me an absence of evidence kind of thing. What if a different solver converges?

Comment: I just tried `fitdistr` from MASS (it just uses `optim`) and it seems to converge. It produced some warnings (nan's produced), but the final values seem fine... These warnings appear even if I run it with an actual generated NB data, so it seems to be an issue with this solver.

Comment: @user77084 the issue of creating a probability model that "explains the data" is a very non-scientific way of going about things. Turn your attention to the "why" of this 0 valued observation rather than the "what". Is there an unobserved process that determines whether someone experiences this event of interest? For instance, you may be measuring mRNA gene expression for a trait that some subjects in the sample do not have. With a 0-inf model, you are estimating a rate *only among individuals with the trait of interest*. If you are interested in fitting a negbinom model that (ctned)

Comment: averages over all observations, the *fitdistr* should theoretically alleviate some of that since it uses a more "shotgun" approach to maximizing the likelihood rather than the profile likelihood approach used in the EM algorithm of `glm.nb`. This one, however, can be quite imprecise for log-linear models in several parameters, but it looks like you are only estimating a *rate* here, so I imagine that it is an adequate approach to the problem.

Comment: Good points! I really am not trying to "explain away" the data by some mathematical gimmick, but to check whether ZINB gets better at fitting it vs NB (standard for this data). This might indicate an additional process (outside of whatever disperses the data) that introduces zeroes and warrant a further investigation. A priori, perhaps just the dispersion in NB might be enough. I believe this is not un-scientific, but a step towards a more scientific explanation. In any case, I do not think my reasons for wanting to compare ZINB vs NB are under question. Nonetheless, thanks for you comments.

Comment: @user77084 the rate parameters become fundamentally different in either case. I am unsure whether the ZINB is properly nested in the NB model, so that the statistical tests are "sane", but I agree with you if the two rates are vastly different, you might consider that as evidence of some unmeasured process affecting these values. Of course, this was based upon what was observed in the data, so these results are "hypothesis generating" rather than "hypothesis confirming".

Comment: You are right again: my next problem was to compare the models. Despite superficial appearances, NB does not seem to be "nested" in ZINB (I am not a statistician, so I just repeat what I have heard :-)) and I was using the Vuong closeness test (it seems to be widely used when comparing ZINB vs NB), but I found at least one (albeit obscure) article that suggests that this might not be appropriate. Although this was not my original question (I am getting stuck on even fitting the models), I will take suggestions on this, if you have ideas (besides Vuong).